# how to run onclick function with the dynamic string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get ID from an API (**ID: food.slug**) now as the value of the ID is **string** I am getting an error.
**index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: apple_iphone_13_pro_max is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**

**This is the code**

```
const showitem = (foods) => {
    const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    for (const food of foods) {

        const newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.classList.add('col')
        newdiv.innerHTML = `
      
        <div class="card" >
            <img src="${food.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                    additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>

            <button onclick="singleitem(${food.slug})">details</button>
        </div>`;
        console.log(food.slug);

        parent.appendChild(newdiv);

   }
}
```

Comment: your missing quotes `onclick="singleitem('${food.slug}')"` so value of `food.slug` is `apple_iphone_13_pro_max` so this is happening `onclick="singleitem(apple_iphone_13_pro_max)"` which `apple_iphone_13_pro_max` is not defined variable, hence the error

Comment: thanks. now its showing status code 404. i think the API is not valid. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You didn't post the code for the API call.  However, if it wasn't working, how did you get `apple_iphone_13_pro_max`?